# Netbeans and android build error

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I set up NBAndroid  to work Netbeans with Android apps.So I create a test application.My problem is when I try to build the application there is the error bellow.The code of the application is that netbeans create.How can I  solve this problem?

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.x509.X500Name at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeSignatureBlock(SignedJarBuilder.java:384)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.close(SignedJarBuilder.java:273)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.sealApk(ApkBuilder.java:795) etc

Comment: I suggest you switch to android studio which is the official IDE for androd development.

Comment: Which Java do you have installed?

Comment: I have 2 jdk The 1.8 and the 1.6.As I understand Netbeans used the 1.8